# Time Scaling Custom Field at Task Summary Levels

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have two problems.

Problem #1:
I am trying to summarize data on a given date within the time scaled array rather than executing a calculation at the task summary levels and projecting it out over a time horizon.
Is there a way to summarizes all task line-item data on a given date?

Problem #2:
I am trying to make the details column represent the name/title of t.cost1, which is "Labor". "Base8. Cost" is too confusing to the end user.
Is there a way to edit the display of baseline8 cost in the details column of the task usage sheet?

[image]

This code takes data from the labor column (t.cost1) and time scales it over the task start and finish dates for tasks line items only.

```vb
Sub TScaleLabor()

    Dim tsv As TimeScaleValue
    Dim tsvs As TimeScaleValues
    Dim t As Task
    Dim D As Date

    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If t.Summary = False And t.Cost1 <> 0 Then
            t.Baseline8Cost = t.Cost1
            D = t.Finish - 1
            If DateDiff("d", t.Start, t.Finish) > 1 Then
                Set tsvs = t.TimeScaleData((t.Start), D, pjTaskTimescaledBaseline8Cost, pjTimescaleDays, 1)
                For Each tsv In tsvs
                    If ActiveProject.Calendar.Period(tsv.StartDate, tsv.EndDate).Working Then
                        Durdays = ((t.Duration) / 60) / 24
                        tsv = t.Baseline8Cost / Durdays
                    End If
                Next tsv
            ElseIf DateDiff("d", t.Start, t.Finish) = 1 Then
                Set tsvs = t.TimeScaleData((t.Start), t.Finish, pjTaskTimescaledBaseline8Cost, pjTimescaleDays, 1)
                For Each tsv In tsvs
                    If ActiveProject.Calendar.Period(tsv.StartDate, tsv.EndDate).Working Then
                        Durdays = ((t.Duration) / 60) / 24
                        tsv = t.Baseline8Cost / Durdays
                    End If
                Next tsv
            End If
        End If
    Next t

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea for your first issue. Instead of summing up each summary group and writing that value to the parent task(s) in the timescale data, just group on the Outline Number field in a statement at the end of your code. This is what I get on a sample file
[Summed up timescaled costs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXvnR.png)

As for your second issue, both Rachel and I already told you Project does not allow renaming detail field descriptions either manually or via VBA. Remember you are using Project in an unconventional way so compromises are needed.

Comment: roger on the second problem. I just wanted to formally state it here. As for the first problem, would you mind sharing your code with me or the line of code you are recommending I place at the end?

Comment: BP130. Between the "next t" and "End Sub" add the following lines of code, On Error Resume Next
ActiveProject.TaskGroups.Add Name:="LaborRollUp", FieldName:="outline number"
GroupApply Name:="LaborRollUp"
On Error GoTo 0. This last statement is only needed if you plan to add more code after this, otherwise the Err cache automatically clears when the procedure ends.

Comment: thanks much! This is working well. How can I edit the "LaborRollUp" group to group by assignments, not tasks? This simple change will solve the problem!

Comment: BP130. Sorry, you lost me. Your screen shot shows a sum value at task summary level and the LaborRollUp group does that. What are you expecting the group by assignments to show?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I realized that I could use assignment costs to time scale data in the task usage field, since they are the drivers of cost. I am currently testing and evaluating a new script that time scales assignment costs. I successfully transitioned assignment time scaled data but am experiencing a few challenges while q/a-ing that calculations were done correctly. I can share my script with you if you are interested in seeing.

Comment: BP130. I did some research to see what might be possible for customizing the grouping function for assignment data. Unfortunately it appears that although the documentation says the Assignment property of GroupCriterion is read/write, in actuality it is read only. However the "group assignments, not tasks" option can be manually selected after the group is created. However I did have issues with the macro you posted. In particular the timescale data is one day short when spread across the Baseline8Cost field. I don't need to see your script, unless you are stuck and open a new question.